# cognos navigation to next + 1 page javascript

Tags: javascript, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-11

I would like to create 3 navigations in Cognos 11 Report from prompt page, to be able to quick navigate to page2, page3 and page4.
Below is script I found in internet, it uses JS and HTML item functionality. I used it in prompt page but Im able to navigate only to NEXT page (=2 page).
Is it possible to adjust this script to be able to navigate to page 3 and 4 also?
I tried different options, but it did not work for me, could you please advise?

```
<script>
function nextPage() {
var ocr= cognos.Report.getReport("_THIS_");
ocr.sendRequest(cognos.Report.Action.NEXT)
}
 </script>
```

Comment: anybody please?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to skip a prompt page or are you trying to "finish" and navigate to a specific report page?  Please don't answer in comments.  Update your question.

Comment: Why are you in Cognos 11 using a JavaScript style that is compatible with Cognos 8?  To be able to use the interactive viewer, you'll need to use RequireJS.  See the Cognos docs.

Comment: And are you asking how to do this, or how to do it using JavaScript?  Those are very different questions.

Answer (score 0):

A while back Cognos introduced the ability to navigate pages via tabs.  Please see
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.doc/t_rptng_view_pges_tabs.html

If you are not going for a specific look and feel,  this approach would not require the use of JavaScript or Extensions.